# Pulumi unexpectedly urlencodes parts of Shared Access Signature (SAS)

Tags: azure, go, pulumi

We have the golang code below to get a Shared Access Signature from Azure. It works but the sas that is printed has some fields, the "date fields", incorrectly urlencoded.

```
...

conStr := ConvertPulumiStringToString(account.PrimaryConnectionString)
httpsOnly := true
now := time.Now()

sas, err := storage.GetAccountBlobContainerSAS(ctx, &storage.GetAccountBlobContainerSASArgs{
        ConnectionString:   <-conStr,
        ContainerName:      "container",
        Expiry:             now.AddDate(10, 0, 0).Format(time.RFC3339),
        HttpsOnly:          &httpsOnly,
        Permissions: storage.GetAccountBlobContainerSASPermissions{
            Add:    false,
            Create: false,
            Delete: false,
            List:   true,
            Read:   true,
            Write:  false,
        },
        Start: now.Format(time.RFC3339),
    })
    println(sas.Sas)
```

We get this `st=2021-03-16T10%3A58%3A24%2B01%3A00`

We expected this format `st=2021-03-16T10:16:30Z`

I have tried looking at the pulumi documentation but it's very limited.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors while using the SAS? Essentially `:` character is getting URL encoded as `%3A` which is perfectly fine.

Comment: You were correct the problem was not that we had urlescaped characters the problem was that the date format we inserted was the wrong format it should be ISO8601 not RFC3339. The reason it was hard to detect this was that RFC3339 gave different formats on different platforms for some reason we haven't figured out yet.

Comment: It's not the platform that makes the format different it's the timezone using

time.now().utc().format(time.rfc3339) would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when using RFC3339 the timezone needs to be UTC to work with Azure and pulumi.

```
conStr := ConvertPulumiStringToString(account.PrimaryConnectionString)
httpsOnly := true
now := time.Now().UTC()

sas, err := storage.GetAccountBlobContainerSAS(ctx, &storage.GetAccountBlobContainerSASArgs{
        ConnectionString:   <-conStr,
        ContainerName:      "container",
        Expiry:             now.AddDate(10, 0, 0).Format(time.RFC3339),
        HttpsOnly:          &httpsOnly,
        Permissions: storage.GetAccountBlobContainerSASPermissions{
            Add:    false,
            Create: false,
            Delete: false,
            List:   true,
            Read:   true,
            Write:  false,
        },
        Start: now.Format(time.RFC3339),
    })
    println(sas.Sas)
```